# Ctrl-Z sometimes requires Enter to return to shell prompt

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal

I'm logged into the terminal (or terminal emulator), read man pages or read a file with `less`, etc.  I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the foreground application, return to the (bash) shell, do something, go back to the full screen application, leave again, etc.

Eventually, but usually not during the first iteration, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> will not bring me to the command prompt but remains in an intermediate state where keyboard input is displayed on the terminal, readline editing is not available, backspace deletion does work and the typed input is given to the shell upon hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Can somebody explain why this is happening and how to disable it?  I have not found any references to this phenomenon on the internet although I have encountered it for years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can explain it, but I don't know a way to fix it. It's been bothering me for years too. At least 20. It's not a single bug in any particular program, but a race condition between 3 programs that are individually behaving as designed, and it's general enough that it applies to many combinations of programs.

When you type `^Z` while reading a man page, you send a `SIGTSTP` to the foreground process group, which consists of the `man` process and its descendants. The pager (`less`) is one of those descendants.

`man` is suspended immediately, but `less` isn't. It has a signal handler. And there's a good reason for that. It has changed the tty mode (so it can read characters as soon as they're typed), and it wants to restore the original mode and tidy up the screen before giving up control. So it does that.

Meanwhile (that's a racy word), the shell has noticed that the `man` process is stopped. And here's the bad part: the shell has no idea that the `less` process exists. Unix processes generally have no way of knowing about their grandchildren. So from the shell's point of view, the job has stopped, even though in reality `less` hasn't finished tidying up yet.

Acting on incomplete information, the shell puts itself back in the foreground, prints a job notification message, set the tty mode for its own line editor, and prints a prompt. But it's racing with `less`, which is still trying to tidy up. While the shell is printing a prompt and setting atty mode, less is busy moving the cursor and clearing the bottom line of the screen (where the `less` prompt was).

Because it's a race, there are many possibly outcomes, depending on the order of operations, but the most annoying one is this:

1. the shell prints the job notification, sets the tty mode for its line editor, and prints a prompt.
2. `less` moves the cursor to the lower left corner, clears the bottom line (erasing the `less` prompt *and* the shell prompt), and restores the generic default tty mode ("cooked" mode).
3. the shell puts itself in the foreground and begins accepting input.

Now you're staring at a blank line preceded by a job notification, with the shell trying to read keypresses, not knowing that the tty has been set back to cooked mode, and therefore won't be sending any input to the shell until a complete line is typed.

You can actually type a command here, and even edit it, if you're clever enough to figure out how to make it work with your input being passed through both the tty's line editor and the shell's line editor, with immediate feedback coming only from the tty's line editor.

It's a messy situation, and fixing it appears to require more coordination between processes than the kernel currently allows. The shell needs a way to query the suspend state of the process group as a whole, and a way to distinguish between grandchild processes like `less` that handle `SIGTSTP` with intent to suspend themselves shortly afterward, and daemon-like grandchildren that are just ignoring `SIGTSTP` with the intent to keep running in the background while the rest of the job is suspended.

Comment: I don't know if it's true. It seems *so* plausible though and explains a lot. +1.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain how SIGTSTP (or a signal in general) is sent to the processes? E.g. has the parent process no way to "intercept" the signal, do some processing, and then "forward" it to the child?